# Interesting facts about partition of positive integers

Tags: number-theory

> Let $n$ be a positive integer. Show that the number of par-
> titions of $n$, having one part more than $\frac n2$
> , is equal to the
> number of partitions of $n$ having more than $\frac n2$
> parts.

To prove this statement, we will use a bijection between the set of partitions of n having one part more than $\frac n2$ and the set of partitions of n having more than $\frac n2$ parts.

Let's first define some notation. $A$ partition of $n$ is a way of writing $n$ as a sum of positive integers, where the order of the summands does not matter. We write a partition of $n$ as $λ = (λ_1, λ_2, ..., λ_k)$, where $λ_1 ≥ λ_2 ≥ ... ≥ λ_k > 0$ and the sum of the $λ_i$'s is $n$.

Let $A$ be the set of partitions of $n$ having one part more than $\frac n2$. That is,

A = {λ = (λ_1, λ_2, ..., λ_k) :  _1 > \frac n2 and λ₂ + ... + λ_k = n - λ_1}.

Let $B$ be the set of partitions of $n$ having more than $\frac n2$ parts. That is,
$B = {μ = (μ_1, μ₂, ..., μ_k) : μ_1 + μ₂ + ... + μ_k > n/2}$.

Now i think there will be a bijection $f: A → B$ .
But how to do this I'm stuck here... please help

Please have a look...give answer

Comment: Please use MathJax throughout.

Comment: The bijection is given by the standard trick of reflecting Young diagrams across the diagonal. See the images on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)).

Comment: The number of partitions of $n$ into $k$ positive parts is equal to the number of partitions of $n$ where the largest part(s) is $k$ for the same reason